# How to create an Android ImageView with automatic pan and zoom?

Tags: java, android

I want to have an ImageView that slowly zooms/scales/pans the image inside of it. I want it to fill the parent container, in my case, the entire phone view, so that it shows no blank spaces around the image.

An example of what I want is how Facebook home works. It slowly either zooms into the image, and back out, or it pans the image across the view slowly. I've looked online at zooming images with gestures, but I can't seem to translate it well so it automatically does it.

Does anyone have any classes or libraries that can mimic the effect that Facebook Home does?

Answer (score 3):

Old question, I know, but in case anyone else stumbles upon this...

I've used KenBurnsView from https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView

Works pretty well for what you're describing!